# how to pass php variables through url

Tags: php, variables, url

I need to pass a php variable using url to use it in the php code of redirected url. The code which I am using for displaying links of users and passing username of clicked link through url is as follows: (I am just using same page, "view.php" when any of the links is clicked for trial)

```html
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
    {
?>
     <a href="http://localhost/profileviews/view.php?name=' . $row['username'] . '"><?php echo $row['username']; ?></a>
<?php 
 }
```

The code to retrieve variable value in view.php is as follows:

```html
$name=$_GET['name'];
echo $name;
```

But what is being displayed in view.php page after clicking a link is not the name of user, but just ' . $row['username'] . '
Is anything wrong with the syntax I've used for passing php varaible $row['username'] ? 
Please help me out! I am new to php.

Comment: It's inside php code `name=<?php echo $row['username'];?>`

Comment: You have closed the php tag

Comment: You need to ensure that any php code is inside php blocks `<?php <PHP CODE HERE> ?>`

Comment: Thank you so much everyone! Your answers worked! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<a href="http://localhost/profileviews/view.php?name= <?php echo $row['username']; ?> . "><?php echo $row['username']; ?></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
    {
?>
     <a href="http://localhost/profileviews/view.php?name=<?php echo $row["username"]; ?>"><?php echo $row['username']; ?></a>
<?php 
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
    echo'<a href="http://localhost/profileviews/view.php?name='.$row['username'].'">'.$row['username'].'</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
    $username = $row['username'];
    echo "<a href='http://localhost/profileviews/view.php?name=$username'>$username</a>";
}
```

If you don't want variable declaration:

```
echo '<a href="http://localhost/profileviews/view.php?name='.$row['username'].'">'.$row['username'].'</a>';
```